# How to chain multiple RX observables and return as a single function

Tags: angular, ngrx

Below I am trying to add some Angular2 generic http error handling for 401 errors which should re-prompt for login details and then retry the http request again.

The problem is that the retry will not work because function will exit before the login has completed. I need a way to chain two or more observables together.

I can see a possible way to do this using Typescripts async/await, but I’m sure there must be an RX style fix for this?

```
request(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs, retry: boolean = true): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.request(url, options) 
        .catch(initialError => {

            console.log(initialError);
            if (initialError.status === 401) {
                // load login screen, and re-auth
                let login = new LoginDetails();
                login.username = 'John';
                login.password = 'John';
                // this will call another observable to load a dialog form and get the credentials

                this.apiAccountLoginPost(login)
                    .subscribe(data => {
                        // save session data
                        localStorage.setItem('session', data.toJSON());
                        // retry the http request again
                        return this.request(url, options); // need to promote this
                    }, error => {
                        // process error
                        return Observable.throw(initialError);
                    });
                // TODO need to return the login retry as a Observable<Response>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Observable.combineLatest(someObservable, anotherObservable).subscribe(response => {
    console.log("this is array of responses: on 0 place you got response from 'someObservable, on 1 from 'anotherObservable'");
    console.log(response);
});
```

But This is not the case in your situation. What you could do is something like:

```
private sendRequest(type: RequestType, url: string, optional?: RequestOptionsArgs, body?: any):Observable<Response> {
return Observable.create((subscriber: any) => {
  someRequest.subscribe(val => {
      console.log("correct one");
      subscriber.next("push something");
  }, (err) => {
      console.log("error handling");
      subscriber.next("push some error");
  });
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do it [with](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/retrywhen.md) `rxjs/add/operator/retryWhen` or `retry`

You can use `next` or `error` method to control your observer.

[see more Reactive programming, HTTP and Angular 2](https://jaxenter.com/reactive-programming-http-and-angular-2-124560.html).